# Meteor restarts client after Meteor.call()

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-react

I'm using: meteor-base@1.4.0.
I want to redirect the user to a different page but after the insert the client it's refreshed. This means that i'm filling up a form, I store the data, I do the navigation and then with the client refresh I'm back to the form page.

```
// Methods.js
import { Meteor } from "meteor/meteor";
import { Players } from "../imports/api/players";

Meteor.methods({
    insertPlayer(player) {
        Players.insert(player);
    }
})
```

I'm calling the method like this:

```
// New-player.jsx
Meteor.call("insertPlayer", player, (error) => {
    if(error) {
        alert("Oups something went wrong: " + error.reason);
    } else {
        this.props.history.push("/");
    }
})
```

And i'm storing the values as:

```
// Players.js
Players.allow({
    insert() { return false; },
    update() { return false; },
    remove() { return false; }
});

Players.deny({
    insert() { return true; },
    update() { return true; },
    remove() { return true; }
})
```

Any idea what it might cause this behavior? 
I'm I missing any config?

The project can be found here: https://github.com/roedit/soccer-app

Comment: Are you using any router?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the react-router-dom. The navigation works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using a form submit event? Make sure before you call the Meteor Method `insertPlayer` you are using `event.preventDefault()`. If you do not event.preventDefault(), the page will refresh.

Comment: Yep, very likely. Submit event is on [this line of code in the repo](https://github.com/roedit/soccer-app/blob/d5a1bcd387c7db2cb32d76252d01d2b61d0800ad/imports/ui/New-player.jsx#L7).